# Change img src in ASP.NET with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image, src

I have a `.aspx` page with an `<img>` tag which has an `src` subject to change depending on some controls values on the page. Pratically I change `src` with a runtime built-in querystring that cause `src` change and and wait for server response (server is returning a `byte[] of the image`).

My issue is that my `<img>` flicker (it becomes white) while is waiting for server's response. How can I update it once the server has done? Can JavaScript and JQuery accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can preload the image and set it when it's preloaded like this:

```
$('<img>').attr('src', 'path/to/image/you/want/to/preload.png')
          .bind('load', function() {
              $('#image-to-replace').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
          });
```

With jQuery, this creates an `<img>`, sets its `src` attribute and attaches an event handler to the image's `load` event so that when the image is done loading, you can set the image's `src` to whatever `#image-to-replace` you have in your markup.